# Expecting ";" when using void

Tags: typescript

I have the method:

```
public static OpenSelectedItem(itemId: string) {
     //Cool Stuff
};
```

When I change it to:

```
public static void OpenSelectedItem(itemId: string) {
//Awesome Stuff
};
```

It throws Expecting ";".  What do I do?

Comment: Leave the `;` in there?

Comment: Sorry edited.  It was in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
public static OpenSelectedItem(itemId: string) : void {
   //Awesome Stuff
}
```

the return type goes after the parameter list with a `:` and not before the method name like in C#.

When you don't specify a return type

```
public static OpenSelectedItem(itemId: string) {
     //Cool Stuff
};
```

it will default to `any` which means your method may or may not have a return statement which may or may not return something.

While if you have the return type `void` the compiler not allow to have `return` statements with arguments (e.g. `return something;`) in your method. But you can still have empty return statements like: `return;`

Comment: @Hubrid: Correct, the return statement should come after the method, not in the method's signature. Edited this answer for clarity and correctness.

Comment: Also, if you specify the return type as `any` you're not required to put a return statement, but it is not forbidden either. If you use `void` as return type, it's not allowed to use a return statement in the body. Please update your answer :)

Comment: @Anzeo In TS the `return` statement is always optional (unless you use some concreate return type like `string`) and never forbidden no matter what is the return type. Specifing the return type just makes the compiler checks what is after the `return` is if you write `void` you cannot return anything and you can only write `return;` with no arguments. Demo: http://bit.ly/12FMKmQ So you can still have return statement in a void method. But I will update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @nemesv I didn't know you could always use the return statement, I was indeed referring to the return type :) Thanks for updating!